# Websphere 8.5 J2C alias password is changing

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-rad

I've got a strange Websphere 8.5 problem and I'm hoping someone else has seen before. I didn't see it here or on Google when I searched for it.

I am working on an app that calls a service via SOAP and it requires a username and password in the request in order get a valid response. To store the login information we are using a J2C Authentication Alias on the server. This is working fine for most of the team, but something is wrong with my local server I have running in RAD, which I need to test code changes.

The alias is set up just like everyone else's, however when I looked at the request that is being sent to the service I noticed the password is being altered. It has a special character `&` as part of the password, and in the request this is being replaced with `&amp` . This causes the service call to fail due to invalid credentials.

I am using the same code as the rest of the team, but they are not seeing this same behavior, hence my belief that there is some setting specific to me. I tried creating a new server from scratch and still see this happening.

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this, or how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like url encoding.
Compare your profile with others in team.

Try setting your WAS profile:

Java and Process Management.
Click Process definition.
In the Additional Properties section, click Java Virtual Machine.
Click New to add the encoding flag:
Name: com.ibm.ws.classloader.encodeResourceURLs
Value: false

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6RHZ_2.0.1/com.ibm.rational.pe.install.doc/topics/t_web_services_was_encode.html

Comment: I just came back to work after a long weekend, I'll try this out. Thanks!